# Sql Server data security in lost laptop scenario

Tags: sql-server, security

The situation is Windows XP laptop with password required for logon, database running in Microsoft Sql Server Developer edition with Windows authentication.

I've been asked to investigate how secure the information would be in the event the laptop was lost or stolen. I'm not quite sure how to characterize it. It seems pretty secure against someone who is only a computer application user as long as he doesn't have the password.

What level of IT/hacker skills is required to recover the data without the password? Any good IT guy? Any good DBA? J Random hacker?  We are interested in identity theft-type info: name, address, SSN, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no problem to mount the data files (*.mdf). in a new SQL Server and access the data in these files, if the data are not encrypted.

Here is an introduction to SQL Server encryption: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

A possible and very(!) safe solution would be to encrypt the whole disk using a tool like TrueCrypt (http://www.truecrypt.org/) - this is standard procedure in industry

Comment: I keep flat file data in a PGP encrypted virtual drive. I read about whole disk encryption but was put off by various warnings. Thanks for the mention of TrueCrypt. PGP has been great, but I've had too many issues with Symantec in the past to be confident they won't screw it up.

Answer (score 0):

Any passible IT guy can get into that, and expose all your data.  Also, if you work for a company where you have to follow SOX or HIPPA, or you do business in California, you'll get in serious trouble.

For a laptop, I'd suggest full-disk encryption.  If it gets stolen, the data on the laptop is useless without the password.   It slows the machine down a bit, but it's solid security.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be sure you really are safe is using complete disk encryption...
http://www.truecrypt.org/ Has free software to do this.
When full disc encryption is used the whole disk can't be accessed unless they get your password (also make sure its a secure password)

Let me explain you what happens with a stolen laptop:
When a hacker has complete access to all the main (windows) files on the disk he is allready able to acces the windows password file, after that using that file the hacker can (with the use of some tools) easily crack into your windows account and from there on he is free to do anything he wants...